# Pandas: Take date from one column and add it to other

Tags: pandas, dataframe

There is dataframe as:

```
time         date    
11:42:14.556 2023-12-10 10:12:00.129465868
11:42:16.005 2023-12-11 15:25:00.759067848
11:42:32.175 2023-12-12 13:56:00.653087940
```

Columns are object types.

How to take date from "date" column and add it to "time" column?

Comment: Can you clarify what are the dtype of the original columns?

Comment: The type of data determines the method.

Comment: All columns are object types

Comment: Thanks @harp1814 for clarifying, then both my approaches should work :)

Comment: @PandaKim the nice thing with `to_datetime` is that it can take a datetime column as input, so in doubt the conversion doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dt.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) after converting [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.normalize().add(pd.to_timedelta(df['time']))
```

Or if both columns are strings, [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the date and concatenate:

```
df['time'] = df['date'].str.extract('(\S+)', expand=False)+' '+df['time']

# or
df['time'] = df['date'].str[:10]+' '+df['time']
```

Output:

```
                     time                           date
0 2023-12-10 11:42:14.556  2023-12-10 10:12:00.129465868
1 2023-12-11 11:42:16.005  2023-12-11 15:25:00.759067848
2 2023-12-12 11:42:32.175  2023-12-12 13:56:00.653087940
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with add times and convert output to datetimes:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.split().str[0] + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str))
```

Or [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.normalize() + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
```

---

```
print (df)
                     time                           date
0 2023-12-10 11:42:14.556  2023-12-10 10:12:00.129465868
1 2023-12-11 11:42:16.005  2023-12-11 15:25:00.759067848
2 2023-12-12 11:42:32.175  2023-12-12 13:56:00.653087940
```